# Should I disavow backlinks from crawler based websites?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks, disavow-links, google-penguin-algorithm

I analysed the backlink profile of my website and found that a lot of websites which generate their data by crawling the web, were pointing to my website.
I have special concerns for this one specific website.
[image: Backlinks]

This website crawls the web for their content and because of its design has a lot of links pointing to my website.
The links are also not tagged as "no-follow". Checking its profile it also does not appear to be a great website.

Any suggestions that should I disavow such domains with backlinks?

Comment: If the links are no-follow, then leave it alone. No harm no foul. Only worry about really bad sites.

Comment: @closetnoc No, they are not no-follow links and now that the Penguin is also real time so I just do not want to risk such low-value unwanted backlinks. Plus I am also seeing a dip in the organic traffic since September

Comment: If Google keeps this up, then there will be no search results for any site. ;-0 Oooohhhhh noooooo! Say it ain't so!! Panda, penguin, we need a bat man to serve justice for us honest webbernaughts!

Comment: @closetnoc till now all we have is a Duck!!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to do anything as long as:

- These sites are linking to thousands of other sites
- You didn't in any way request to get listed (the linking site added all the links on their own volition).
- You don't have any manual actions against your site listed in Google Search Console.

Google can't penalize linked sites from a site like this.   There are just too many sites linked and none of the linked site owners can do anything about it.

The only time that you need to disavow links is when there is some sort of penalty against your site that needs to be dealt with.

Comment: +1 You shouldn't have to explicitly disavow these links. Google probably already knows about this "crawler website" and is probably already _ignoring_ (in terms of ranking) the links. (I'm sure I've heard Matt Cutts mention this in one of his videos.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use disavow tools, if your site does not have too much good backlinks. Big sites like Amazon, Facebook and twitter does not care about bad links that point to you, also it is painful for big webmster to analyse all kind of website, so generally Google may use some kind of ratio, to know weather this site deserve any penalty or not.

So, If you'r site is new and have not many good backlinks, then always always use disavow tools, if you disavow them then it does not mean you have just stop some juicyrank that passes to your webpage, generally that kind of website does not have any value or very little value which might does not help you in ranking. So use them, you're just stopping that bucket who have only 1 mm Water.

Comment: Thanks Goyllo. I am inclined towards disavowing them. It is just that people tell not to be too aggressive with disavowing.

Comment: They are right, mostly G ignore those links, but still to play safe, I will say use disavow tool because in reality those links have no such value. If I was there, then I will check that site carefully, and see weather they links to only good sites or not. If it is link farm site, and point to many spammy links with yours, then I will say please please use disavow tools, because that's how Google spam algorithm works. Hope you got my point :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same concerns in the past, but I left them to, be as they are. The positions of my websites haven't dropped off after any Google update. However, it depends on the website you are getting the links from. If it is trustworthy like Amazon, it is fine... but if it's not, disavow them (just to be sure).